# How to use Nashorn? How it improve performance?

Tags: java, javascript

I recently started learning nashorn. I was amazed to see that we can now run javascript from our java code. I want to know does it actually improve performance of the system if we use javascript instead of whole java code. Will it not make context switching to call js and returning back?

Another part of my question: 
I tried creating a test project, and able to run js from the java code.

```
public class JSFromJava {
static class JavaClass {
    int intValue;
    String data;
    long longValue;
    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }
    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public long getLongValue() {
        return longValue;
    }
    public void setLongValue(long longValue) {
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JavaClass [intValue=" + intValue + ", data=" + data
                + ", longValue=" + longValue + "]";
    }


}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    // read script file
    engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("e:/js/a.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
    // call function from script file
    Object op = inv.invokeFunction("incrementValueByTen", 2);
    System.out.println(op);

    JavaClass jc = new JavaClass();
    jc.intValue=2;
    jc.longValue=56;
    jc.data="data";
    System.out.println(jc);
    inv.invokeFunction("updateJavaObject", jc);
    System.out.println(jc);
}
```

}

Javascript file:

```
function incrementValueByTen(arg) {
return arg + 10;
```

}

```
function updateJavaObject(arg) {
    print("arg recieved::::"+arg)
    print(arg.getIntValue())
    arg.setIntValue(5);
    arg.data=incrementValueByTen(arg.data);
    arg.longValue=incrementValueByTen(arg.longValue);
    print("arg updated::::"+arg)
}
```

As we can see, I am trying to update a java object or use the java object passed to second function. I am getting issues saying that the arg is not having those methods. All the properties are also coming as null.

First method is working perfectly as it is consuming primitive type.

Does this mean, that we cannot pass java objects to any method as parameter?

Please suggest.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: I have not tried it, but I see no reason why using JavaScript should improve performance. I expect exactly the opposite: performance will go down dramatically. The advantage of using JS in your application is to make it sciptable, i.e change parts of its logic without having to compile and re-deploy your application.

Comment: I just heard too much about js engines performing much better than jvms. Might be the nashorn engine might not be effective enough. Not really sure. JS gives much more support to go for parallel processing. I am not an expert in js, but lot of stuffs are told about js and its engine.

Comment: Maybe I'm biased, proramming in Java for the last 17 years. I have an idea on how much optimization has been put into JVMs during that time. I don't know too much about JS through. Maybe I'm wrong. Just try it, and see what happens...

Comment: Nashorn is a Javascript engine that runs on top of a Java engine.  It would surprise me greatly if you could take a typical Java algorithm, recode it in Javascript, run it on Nashorn, and get better performance than running the original Java on the same platform.  (Of course, if you picked a problem that Javascript was naturally better at ... JS could win over Java.  But a *typical* Java program?  No.)

Comment: @Amit: Why exactly do you think "JS gives much more support to go for parallel processing."?

Comment: You are correct Stephen, I thought we are having another js engine which will run in parallel with jvm. On further reads, I could find that the js will be converted to bytecodes and will be run on jvm which means actual execution is via jvm engine and not any js engine. JS by default supports closure etc, to let us write async code. you dont have to write much for actually implementing async.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `JavaClass` is not public; if a Java class is not public, its methods are also effectively not public, even though you declare them as "public" except if they override a superclass method or implement an interface method that the class implements. That's not a Nashorn specific issue, it's generally true that you can't invoke public methods on a non-public class, except if they're declared on a public superclass or implemented interface. If you change it to `public static class JavaClass` you should be able to invoke its methods from JS.

As for "context switching from JS to Java and back"; there's no such thing. Nashorn compiles JS programs to Java bytecode classes and the invocation of Java methods from JS is done using the INVOKEDYNAMIC instruction; HotSpot generally links it as efficiently as an INVOKEVIRTUAL (which is what a compiled Java code would do to call the method), with the caveat that in JS it actually looks quite different. E.g. while in Java it'd look like:

```
ALOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL "int JavaClass.getIntValue()"
```

in Nashorn it'll actually be

```
ALOAD 1
INVOKEDYNAMIC "dyn:getMethod:getIntValue"
ALOAD 1
INVOKEDYNAMIC "dyn:call"
```

(so, two INVOKEDYNAMICs: one to retrieve the method on the class, another to invoke it; in JS all method invocations are such two-step).

You can also use the property getter syntax:

```
print(arg.intValue)
```

in which case `arg.intValue` is compiled to

```
ALOAD 1
INVOKEDYNAMIC "dyn:getProp:intValue"
```

which the linker machinery knows to translate to an invocation of `getIntValue()` on your object. So when you can, property getter syntax actually ends up compiling to smaller bytecode (which isn't necessarily faster, mind you, but it's a good bet that it marginally is).